# Firefox cannot (did not) copy previous firefox configuration(s) into the new SNAP "stuff" during upgrade of 20.04.1 to 22.04.1

Tags: upgrade, python

Firefox was at Version 101 or higher, and after the upgrade to UBUNTU 22.04.1, it is now in a SNAP environment and is version 103.  The SNAP environment is PREVENTING access to to my HOME PAGE and asociated Doc files, and the SNAP version did not "import" any of the previous FireFox configuration information. (bookmarks, passwords, Gnome extensions, etc)

1. Before the upgrade, firefox displayed and used my -LOCAL- HTML home page without difficulty. The home page is a local file and is written in HTML with hundreds of external site references and links to local documentation files also written in HTML.  I have been using this technique since FireFox version 48 in 2016...
   (Since most of the information displayed via my home page is personal, it is not appropriate to place the files where the installed "test" APACHE server can access them, since external access to the server is allowed from time to time for remote testing.)
2. The bookmark files, passwords, etc. were not transferred from the old firefox installation directory to the "new" one.
3. I have been unable to find a way to "import" or otherwise load the missing information - or to place the files where the FIREFOX snap environment can access them.  (Don't ask how I feel about the "snap" sandbox that FireFox is now in.  This -IS- a family website! )
4. This upgrade has been a nightmare. As a minor starter, PYTHON3 would not install because of an incompatible python "script" called "renpy" (that I did not install) - and as a result of that script most of the rest of the 22.04.1 upgrade failed, because "PYTHON3 was not installed". It took three long days to discover that the original install would automatically restart as soon as I used APT to remove "renpy".

I have no idea if my FIREFOX problems are somehow related to the PYTHON3 issues... (when I tried to "reinstall" FIREFOX using SNAP to see if that would fix anything, nothing happened and SNAP reported that the FireFox update was already installed.

UPDATE: By removing the SNAP version of FIREFOX and using APT to install a "standalone" version of FIREFOX, all problems with Firefox disappeared.

Comment: After your UPDATE, what question remains? You may want to delete this question.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem after updating several 20.04 desktops to 22.04.

Comment: (1) Did any of those updates have locally defined home pages? (2) Did PHYTHON3 fail during the original install?

Comment: Vanadium: There needs to be a dialog of sorts on this. I was unable to find quick help after the original install. Yes, I have it "working", but what about after the next SNAP update?

Comment: There is a way to prevent future snap upgrades from impacting on the APT version of FF.. You might care to look at [this resource](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04) and [this one too](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/). These arrangements do work. I have the APT version now installed on 22.04 and there are no issues with snap upgrades putting FF back as a snap on my system.

Comment: There is no "*next SNAP update*" planned, nor is there a need for "*a dialog of sorts*". The transition that --from your description-- failed (for you, not for everybody) was migrating your Firefox profile from /home/.config to /home/.snap. It's a bit more complex than simply copying it, but it was a one-time transition. Snap-to-snap upgrades are frequent and painless. We don't know why your Firefox migration failed; perhaps your logs might have clues for a bug report if you are interested in finding a real solution. Reporting a bug is off-topic here.

Comment: 24601: Thanks for the two references, this morning I found something similar but had not yet implemented it.

Comment: user535733: I disagree that "there is no need for a dialog of sorts." The comments made here have already caused some folks to think about the overall issue... I do agree that it is a bit more complex then just copying the files, I tried that and it did not work.  What bothers me is that "the one-time migration did fail" and I will be looking at the logs to see if I can determine what caused the failure. Unfortunately even if the migration had worked, my home page would not have worked because of SNAP sandbox security. If I can determine probable causes, I will report it as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: By removing the SNAP version of FIREFOX and using APT to install a "standalone" version of FIREFOX, all problems with Firefox disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to copy /home/username/.mozilla to the appropriate place in the snap firefox folder. I would say launch the snap firefox and then close it. Go into the snap firefox folder. NOTE the snap folder in your home folder. See where the .mozilla folder is inside the snap firefox folder and replace it with the one from /home/username/.mozilla. Hopefully that would solve your issue. I have not tested this but it could be the possible solution.

Comment: While I do not remember all of the things that were tried over the past three or four days, I believe I did what you suggested and found that while some of the "migration" aspects would be fixed, I still could not use my home page and/or local documentation files because of the SNAP sandbox security.  It would not have been practical to have moved all of those files inside the sandbox either.  But thanks for the thought.

Comment: I really do not like snap, having a store that has some really older versions of software that are seemingly not maintained. Are the snap packages even tested for quality, integrity (security)?? Microsoft and Ubuntu want to copy what apple and android did with phones and definitely want to monetize those stores. Pretty simple really remove all snap apps and use apt versions only if possible. As you mentioned also snap goes directly against handling the applications in the standard Linux way which is to put a .application-name folder in your home folder. I hope they eventually abandon snap.